# Mail Mac automatically creates a link, even if I remove it manually

Tags: mail.app, links

When composing an email using Mail Mac (OS X El Capitan), if I write *something .cc*, an hyperlink is automatically created. Since I do not want this, I manually remove the link. Anyway, when the email is sent, in the inbox folder the link appears again.
Is there a way to prevent Mail to automatically add the link after I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can disable smart links and use `Cmd+K` instead when you want to add link manually.

[image]

Comment: I have _smart links_ option disabled and, when I write the email, no links seem to be present (no blue underscores). However, after sending it, links automatically appear again.

Comment: oh, that is only while you view in apple mail (in sent items). try sending it to e.g. gmail address, you wont see the hyperlinks there.